# Как задать ширину ячейки td?

Tags: javascript, html, css

как задать ширину ячейки `td` в jquery,у каждого `td` свой класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например [так](http://jsfiddle.net/GXnrF/1/)  - на jQuery или [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/u4wGq/1/) - "обычным" способом

Answer (score 0):

Можно применить атрибут width (в %,px,em и т.д.) напрямую к html тегам или в css